# How to remove the millisecond part of HH:MM:SS.[sss] using sed?

Tags: linux, bash, sed, command-line

I have a CSV file with a time column where all times come in HH:MM:SS.[sss]  format. how do i remove all the millisecond parts? i.e., change all times in form of 09:30:00.000 to 09:30:00

You can even assume the first column is always time, if that helps...

Answer (score 0):

I will show you how to use the "date" command.

```sh
$ date -d "09:30:00.000" +%H:%M:%S
09:30:00
```

If you want to set VALUE, look at the follow.

```
YMD=$(date -d "09:30:00.000" +%H:%M:%S)
```

Answer (score -1):

Here's a sample:

```
$ echo "09:30:00.000" | sed 's/\..*//g'
09:30:00
$
```

Please add the filters for column, and delimiters (say comma, given it's CSV) in the pattern.

Comment: Probably a bit to general to delete all characters after all periods in a csv file?